# Issues with Resharper Search with Pattern/Structural Replacement functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resharper, structural-search

I am trying to use Resharper's *Search with Pattern/Structural Replacement* functionality to find (cs)html fragments like the following, with the end goal of replacing said code with an editor template:

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
```

I am using the following pattern, but I receive an error saying that the search pattern could not be parsed:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.$propertyName$)
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.$propertyName$)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.$propertyName$, new { @class = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.$propertyName$)
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me:

- If I am doing something wrong
- If Resharper's pattern functionality is capable of dealing with HTML
- If Resharper's pattern functionality is capable of dealing with multiline patterns

Thanks in advance

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper 6.0 doesn't support SSR in HTML, but 6.1 will.
But still, only plain HTML (in html, aspx, cshtml files), but not Razor constructions, like @Html.
So, your pattern will not work even in 6.1.

P.S. Yes, ReSharper is capable of handling multiline patterns.